# mingw -fvisibility=hidden does not seem to work

Tags: shared-libraries, mingw, visibility

I have a shared library which is supposed to export only one function which is marked with `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`. It also links with another static library (fftw), and

```
#include<fftw3.h>
```

is preceded with:

```
#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)
```

The linker command used:

```
g++.exe -fvisibility=hidden -shared -o mylib.dll -Wl,--out-implib,mylib.dll.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive libfftw3.a libfftw3_omp.a -lgomp
```

Now the resulting library is huge and if I check the exported functions it includes ALL fftw functions, and ALL function from my files. It looks like mingw ignores visibility options. I read that previously it gave warning about `-fvisibility`, but now it compiles with no warnings whatsoever.

Does mingw and gcc 4.6.1 support visibility flags? If yes, how do I get rid of all unnecessary stuff in my shared library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows PE object files do not have visibility attributes. The closest is dllexport/dllimport, but that's only for shared libraries (DLL's). So either you don't mark all FFTW functions with `__declspec(dllexport)`, and hope linking the static library does `The Right Thing (tm)`, or you take care not to link to FFTW if linking with your library.

It should warn about bad visibility attributes, perhaps you need to turn up the warning level `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`).

Answer (score 4):

Mingw is a Windows port of GCC toolchain but Windows `dll` are not Linux `so`. Especially [the link part is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251171/architecturally-what-is-the-difference-between-a-shared-object-so-and-a-dynami). To specify the visibility with MingGW you have to go the Windows way and annotate your classes and functions with :

- `__declspec(dllexport)` while compiling the library
- `__declspec(dllimport)` while linking

If you want multiplatform support for the GCC toolchain you can add a header in your project doing that for you. For a step by step example and lots of details [have a look at GCC's visibility guide](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).