# Dynamic Shared Object equivalent on windows

Tags: windows, object, dynamic, dll, shared

The Dynamic Shared Object library on Linux is approximately equal the dll in Windows. That's what I found online. But there are some differences and they are explained here: [Architecturally what is the difference between a shared object (SO) and a dynamic link library (DLL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251171/architecturally-what-is-the-difference-between-a-shared-object-so-and-a-dynami)

Then I am confused:

1. In linux one can use -shared to create a DSO library, then link with -lmylib. But in windows, things are different. One have to add dllexport into the code. Only the "exported" part can be linked (If I am correct). Is there a option to make windows dll link-able without adding dllexport? (I tried to make a dll with just functions and no dllexport, but what I can tell so far is that the dll without dllexport is something useless, right?)
2. What does MinGW do? I thought it create dlls in the days when I used it. But now I think the library that created by MinGW-gcc -shared is something else. Is it windows version lib.so? Can MSVS/intel compiler do the similar thing?

I am asking these because of cross platform issues. For example, a linux code can be compiled without any changes on windows machine. But if one want to create a dll by using the code (compiled with MSVS) which is equivalent to the .so without modifying code (adding dllexport), it is impossible. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a option to make windows dll link-able without adding
>   dllexport?

No, you need `dllexport`.

I have no idea what you mean by the second question, sorry.

> Am I right?

Correct me if I'm wrong but you're restating your first question. So yes you're right, you can't do that. you need `dllexport`.

Comment: Thanks OJ. Then using the static lib will be the only choice since the size of exe doesn't matter.

Comment: If you want to share code easily without dllexports then yes that seems to be your best option.