# Converting Windows' DLL to Linux shared lib

Tags: linux, windows, dll, shared-libraries

I have a DLL developed on windows and I must integrated in an application running in a Linux environment.(Ubuntu 20)
I tried loading the DLL in a windows machine and it works fine.
In the next step, I tried to convert the DLL to linux environment using winegcc but it failed with this following error:

```
gcc: warning: mathlib.dll: linker input file unused because linking not done
winebuild: mathlib-sikQeM.o is an empty file
winegcc: /usr/lib/wine/winebuild faile
```

The command I used to convert the DLL is the following:

```
winegcc -m64 -shared -o mathlib.so mathlib.dll
```

Comment: Read/reflect/act-upon [mcve] . Readers need the smallest amount of code that will help them duplicate the problem. Please update your question. Did you search here first? ~340 Q/A on  your topic. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540491/620097 gives you a hint. Good luck.